# When would it be advised to use a ThreadLocal singleton instead of a request attribute?

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest, thread-local

If my ThreadLocal singleton is only going to be alive for the life of the request anyhow, then why not just use a request attribute? Is this just an easy way to get at a context in a single thread without having to pass through or get to the request object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My opinion is, that using a request attribute is more preferable than using a `ThreadLocal` variable.

It makes code cleaner and you don't have to worry about cleaning the `ThreadLocal` (as it might be re-used be in context of another request which re-uses the same thread).

Though, properly designed and coded local request storage via `ThreadLocal` is fine, if usage of `ThreadLocal` is encapsulated and you don't simply share an instance between different classes (and it's life-cycle is properly handled).

Answer (score 1):

In larger multi-tiered applications you don't generally want to be assuming that the scope of the work is a web request, or having dependencies on inherently 'web' things down inside the lower tiers.  What if you execute this unit of work as a background job?  Or it arrives via some legacy binary interface you end up supporting?

Comment: That is a good point. As it relates to my current scope of work it is all web based.

Answer (score 1):

The drawbacks of using a ThreadLocal singleton are the same as the drawbacks of using a singleton in any other context.  You lose encapsulation, re-usability, and the ability to mock out functionality.

The advantages are ease of use, type safety (no cast), and possibly performance (but probably insignificant in the overall scheme of things).

I would recommend against using a ThreadLocal singleton unless the functionality is well encapsulated and only accessed in very high level layers of the code (explicitly passing your context into deeper classes and functions instead of having them access the singleton).